ReactiveSearch MultiList sorting not working when an item is selected
I implemented an easy sort that sorts items either by count or alphabetically. This function works well initially, passing either 'asc' or 'count' to the sortBy prop without issue. However, when I select an item from the list and then attempt to sort it again—either by count or alphabetically—it fails to re-filter the items. Although the prop updates successfully each time I click, it does not trigger a re-filtering of the items.
I attempted to force a re-render by passing a key prop, but it did not resolve the issue. The functionality is supposed to re-filter the list each time, even when an item has been selected. If I select an item and then choose to sort by count or asc, it should sort accordingly.
import React from 'react';
import { MultiList } from '@dapclient/components/search-core';
import { react } from '@appbaseio/reactivesearch/lib/types';
import FilterAltIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FilterAlt';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';

export const PROJECT_REACTIVE_ID = 'ProjectFilter';

interface ProjectFilterProps {
  fixedValue?: string;
  react?: React.ReactNode;
}

interface ProjectFilterState {
  sortAlphabetically: boolean;
  anchorEl: null | HTMLElement;
}

export default class ProjectFilter extends React.Component<ProjectFilterProps, ProjectFilterState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sortAlphabetically: false,
      anchorEl: null
    };

    this.handleMenuOpen = this.handleMenuOpen.bind(this);
    this.handleMenuClose = this.handleMenuClose.bind(this);
    this.handleSort = this.handleSort.bind(this);
  }

  handleMenuOpen(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  }

  handleMenuClose() {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
  }

  handleSort(sortAlphabetically: boolean) {
    this.setState({ sortAlphabetically, anchorEl: null });
  }

  render = () => {
    const { fixedValue } = this.props;
    const { sortAlphabetically, anchorEl } = this.state;

    return (
      <div style={fixedValue ? {'display': 'none'} : {}}>
        <MultiList
          className="data-filter"
          componentId={PROJECT_REACTIVE_ID}
          dataField="project_name.keyword"
          title={
            <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
              <span>Project</span>
              <FilterAltIcon onClick={this.handleMenuOpen} style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} />
              <Menu
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                onClose={this.handleMenuClose}
              >
                <MenuItem onClick={() => this.handleSort(false)}>Sort by Count</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={() => this.handleSort(true)}>Sort Alphabetically</MenuItem>
              </Menu>
            </div>
          }
          filterLabel="Project"
          showSearch={false}
          react={this.props.react}
          URLParams={!Boolean(fixedValue)}
          defaultValue={fixedValue ? [fixedValue] : undefined}
          showFilter={!Boolean(fixedValue)}
          sortBy={sortAlphabetically ? 'asc': 'count'}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
}



import React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { MultiList as BaseMultiList } from '@appbaseio/reactivesearch';

import CheckboxGrid, {
  FilterItem,
  ValueType,
} from '@extensions/components/search-core/CheckboxGrid';
import FilterTitle from '@extensions/components/search-core/FilterTitle';

type BaseMultiListProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof BaseMultiList>;

export interface IMultiListProps
  extends Omit<
    BaseMultiListProps,
    'render' | 'renderItem' | 'innerClass' | 'showCheckbox'
  > {
  title: string;
  maxLabelWidth?: string;
  /** Should their be a border at the bottom? */
  showBottomBorder?: boolean;
}

interface RenderArgs {
  loading: boolean;
  error: object;
  data: FilterItem[];
  value: ValueType;
  handleChange: (event: { target: { value: string } }) => void;
}

const StyledDiv = styled('div', {
  shouldForwardProp: (props) => props !== 'showBottomBorder',
})<{ showBottomBorder?: boolean | undefined }>(({ showBottomBorder, theme }) => ({
  borderBottom: showBottomBorder ? `1px solid ${theme.palette.grey['400']} ` : ''
}));

class MultiList extends React.Component<
  IMultiListProps
> {
  render() {
    const { title, maxLabelWidth, showBottomBorder, ...baseProps } =
      this.props;
    const titleElementId = `${this.props.componentId}-title`;
    return (
      <BaseMultiList
        {...baseProps}
        showCheckbox={true}
        showSearch={false}
        render={({ loading, error, ...renderProps }: RenderArgs) => {
          if (
            loading ||
            error ||
            !renderProps.data ||
            renderProps.data.length === 0
          ) {
            return null;
          }
          return (
            <StyledDiv showBottomBorder={showBottomBorder}>
              <FilterTitle id={titleElementId}>{title}</FilterTitle>
              <CheckboxGrid
                {...renderProps}
                checkboxColumnHeader={title}
                labeledBy={titleElementId}
                maxLabelWidth={maxLabelWidth}
              />
            </StyledDiv>
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default MultiList;

